# Can read but cannot write to property File with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using a property file for some configurable values. But I do not know why  I can read the property value but when I want to update the existing or write a new key/value pair it is not working

```
Properties props = new Properties();

        try 
        {
            String key = "maxHolidays";

            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config.properties");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            props.load(in);
            String maxHolidays = (String) props.get(key);
            System.out.println(maxHolidays);  

            props.setProperty("newkey", "newvalue");

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            props.store(out, null);
```

I finally found the solution. All answers here were basically not right. It is possible to change a property file during runtime. The only mistake I made was not closing the Inputstream when opening the Outputstream. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:First.properties");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    System.out.println(props.getProperty("country"));
    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    props.setProperty("country", "germany");
    props.store(out, null);
    System.out.println(props.getProperty("country"));
    out.close();
```

But what is really annoying that no Exception was thrown. That cost me 3 days to solve this issue. Operating system seems to block writing to file when InputStream is still open. But again I expect some exception to be thrown what is not the case.

Comment: You can't modify anything in the resouce folder, you need to have a separate property file  on disk outside of you jar file

Comment: your code change the config.properties.file in the build/compiled folder. E.g if u use intellij it will load the file in the target\classes\config.properties. if you check the file there it already has new value "newkey=newvalue"

Comment: No it has no new value !!!!  But I use Eclipse . All I do does not work . Where exactly should I put the resource file. It costs me quite some time now.

Comment: using ResourceUtils you just need to change "classpath:" into "file:". check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should works,

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    try {
        String key = "maxHolidays";

        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("file:config.properties");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        props.load(in);
        String maxHolidays = (String) props.get(key);
        System.out.println(maxHolidays);

        props.setProperty("newkey", "newvalue");

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        props.store(out, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

put your config.properties in the root of your project folder

Comment: I put it in the root folder. just the same level as src folder but it does not find the file at all now.

Comment: try using "file:./config.properties" or full path "file:/home/user/test/config.properties"

Comment: What is this file: prefix . I did not even know this exists.

Comment: you mean dot "." ? it is prefix for linux os for the same folder that run the jar

Comment: no I mean this """file""""" prefix . Why can I use it. I cannot use full path . I need to use relativ path anyway

Comment: read this[https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html] in the section FILE_URL_PREFIX

Comment: If I give full path it works. Otherwise not. But I cannot use full path because I will deploy it to some other server !